# How to center-align an image in an SVG clip-path?

Tags: css, svg, path, clip-path

I have an image that is clipped using an SVG clipPath. However I'd like that the image is center-aligned horizontally & vertically within the clipPath.

Is there a way to do this?

```
<!-- SVG Reference -->
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath2">
      <path fill="#00B6B5" d="M262.229,81.068l-29.486-66.662
                              c-1.598-3.248-4.91-5.309-8.537-5.309H17.394c-6.408,0-10.596,6.703-7.773,12.441l26.736,61.072
                              c1.697,3.449,1.676,7.494-0.059,10.926L9.827,152.482c-2.902,5.742,1.283,12.521,7.732,12.521h206.715
                              c3.592,0,6.879-2.018,8.494-5.217l29.387-64.717C264.378,90.671,264.405,85.49,262.229,81.068z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<!-- SVG Reference -->

<div class="arrow-cards">
  <img src="http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg" style="clip-path: url(#svgPath2); -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath2);">
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/LGqMVq

Answer (score 4):

Your clip path uses absolute coordinates, so it is basically fixed on the page.
You could set the img dimensions to match the size of the arrow shape (approx 258x156). But that would stretch the image out of shape.

Or you could keep the aspect ratio of the image correct by setting just the width of the image to 258. Then centre it by using relative positioning to shift it up a bit..

```css
body, svg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  clip-path: url(#svgPath2);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath2);
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- SVG Reference -->
<svg height="0px" width="0px">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath2">
      <path fill="#00B6B5" d="M262.229,81.068l-29.486-66.662
                              c-1.598-3.248-4.91-5.309-8.537-5.309H17.394c-6.408,0-10.596,6.703-7.773,12.441l26.736,61.072
                              c1.697,3.449,1.676,7.494-0.059,10.926L9.827,152.482c-2.902,5.742,1.283,12.521,7.732,12.521h206.715
                              c3.592,0,6.879-2.018,8.494-5.217l29.387-64.717C264.378,90.671,264.405,85.49,262.229,81.068z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<!-- SVG Reference -->

<div class="arrow-cards">
  <img src="http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg" width="258">
</div>
```

Or an easier approach would be to set the containing `div` to the size of the arrow shape and apply the clip to that. The image would be centred by using `background-szie: cover`.

```css
body, svg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.arrow-cards {
  width: 265px;
  height: 165px;
  background-image: url(http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/4f3433986bb3f7b67a00003c/a-parasite-found-in-cats-could-be-manipulating-our-brains.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: url(#svgPath2);
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#svgPath2);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-cards"></div>

<!-- SVG Reference -->
<svg height="0px" width="0px">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="svgPath2">
      <path fill="#00B6B5" d="M262.229,81.068l-29.486-66.662
                              c-1.598-3.248-4.91-5.309-8.537-5.309H17.394c-6.408,0-10.596,6.703-7.773,12.441l26.736,61.072
                              c1.697,3.449,1.676,7.494-0.059,10.926L9.827,152.482c-2.902,5.742,1.283,12.521,7.732,12.521h206.715
                              c3.592,0,6.879-2.018,8.494-5.217l29.387-64.717C264.378,90.671,264.405,85.49,262.229,81.068z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<!-- SVG Reference -->
```

If you are intending to have the arrow shapes at various positions on the page, you'll probably want to look at defining your clip paths with `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"`.  That way, it can be applied to an element anywhere on the page and will adjust to fit the element shape.